# Can't get flush() working in Windows

Tags: php, apache2

We have a ubuntu test server that this simple script works fine on where it outputs a number each second to the browser

```
<?
    for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) 
    {
        echo $i.'<br>';
        flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
```

However on my local development box (windows environment) I cannot get it to work, it outputs it all after 3 seconds.

I am using the same php version (5.3.13) as well as apache (2.2.22) version on my local box as the test server.
I have mirrored most of the settings in both php.ini as well as the httpd.conf
Here are settings I have set (which are identical to the test server)

```
output_buffering 0
zlib.output_compression = Off
zlib.output_compression_level = -1
```

I don't have mod_gzip installed.

I have even tried doing a wamp install on my box, and it didn't work with that either.

I can't imagine it being a client (browser -- firefox 13) issue as I use the exact same browser to view the script on the test server and it works fine

I have tried enabling implicit flush, doing ob_flush, etc. No luck.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?

Comment: The webserver can buffer, the browser can buffer (MSIE famously doesn't render until it has a certain minimal amount of output), any server-hop can buffer, etc. HTTP/HTML pages should never considered to be a 'running console', however much people like it to be.

Comment: I remember a while ago I ran into same issue, I had reconsider the whole handling logic. I ended up getting the "dynamic" data from PHP with `text/plain` type and doing the cool HTMLy stuff with Javascript. In other words, put this in the beginning of your code `header('Content-type: text/plain');`

Comment: Sorry my boss came in to talk to me. Setting that header did not help

Comment: I agree wrikken, however I am writting a CLI processing script that will take 30min+ to run each time, and during development I want to flush to the browser so that I can kill the process if the output isn't right. I will change the flush to logging once I put it into production and make it execute as a cron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just keep in mind what @Wrikken said, this is not recommended.

So I was thinking, everything you're doing seems to be right. I copied your setup and tried. I faced same problem. I executed the script from command line, it worked.

Then I had to do the last test, Wireshark. Following the first couple of packets it was clear that the server is sending everything correctly, so it had to be the browser’s buffer.

So I tried send some data before the loop, well guess what? It worked!

Here you go:

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering','off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
echo str_repeat(" ", 1024), "\n";
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
      echo $i."<br />\n";
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(1);
}
?>
```

I'm not sure about the application you have in mind, but this is clearly not a good idea, I highly recommend that you look into other options.

**Update:**
After a lengthy Google search I found [this](http://gtmetrix.com/specify-a-character-set-early.html) and [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rendering)

> Because a browser cannot correctly render a page without knowing how
>   to construct the page's characters, most browsers buffer a certain
>   number of bytes before executing any JavaScript or drawing the page

And

> To avoid these delays, you should always specify the character
>   encoding as early as possible, for any HTML document larger than 1 KB
>   (**1024 bytes**, to be precise, which is the maximum buffer limit used by
>   any of the browsers we have tested).

So I tried to send the charset first instead of filling the buffer: (and it worked)

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering','off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
//echo str_repeat(" ", 1024), "\n";
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
//Note that it shoudn't matter which charset you send
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
      echo $i."<br />\n";
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(1);
}
?>
```

**So why was it working with the first server but not the second?**

Most likely it's because your first server is sending the charset with the header while the second one isn't.

In your case, however, I'd make the following changes

```
<?php
ini_set('output_buffering','off');
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
//Plain text MIME type since you'll use for logging purposes
//and if you run it from CLI, you can ignore the whole header line
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1');
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++) {
      //No need to echo <br /> once you'll run it from CLI
      echo $i."\n";
      ob_flush();
      flush();
      sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! The reason I need it is that I am doing a processing heavy script that will take 30min+ to run that I will be running as a cron once a week in the CLI. During development I want to flush so that I can make sure it is runs through the whole thing properly without having to wait until it is done executing. I will turn the flush into logging once I am sure it works properly.

Comment: One thing I don't get though, is if it is the browsers buffer how come it works fine when I am running the script on the ubuntu server, but not my local server (I am using the browser on my machine in both cases)

Comment: Thanks for the research. As you can see from my other answer I did find the solution, but it is nice to know the why of it instead of just guessing. I did check my test server and I did have UTF8 set as default charset. I thought I had all settings mirrored but obiously I missed that one. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for my problem.
FOr some reason adding the line

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
```

To my php.ini makes it work.
I confirmed my removing the line.. flush didn't work.
Added it, and it worked. Maybe because it adds extra headers giving enough for the browser buffer.