# flush and ob flush are not working

Tags: php

here is my code. The `ob_flush()` and `flush()` functions are not working. Why?

```
<?php
function get_headers_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY,         true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        4);
    $r = curl_exec($ch);
    $r = split("\n", $r);
    return $r;
} 

$urls = file('users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $headers = get_headers_curl(trim($url));
    if (false !== stripos(implode("\n", $headers), "Apache")) {
        echo "$url ====> ok" ;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please give some more info.. What happens? does it execute the whole script and output it as normal or? What environment are you using? I had a similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252342/cant-get-flush-working-in-windows

Comment: @kris no it is not that the problem is that there is no result for each url since all the operation finish it show the result i want the result for each url

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with flush command, there are a few things you need to check.

In php.ini file (or ht access, or even in the script)
set these following values

```
output_buffering 0
zlib.output_compression = Off
zlib.output_compression_level = -1

default_charset = "utf-8"
```

Also I notice in your code you do not have ob_start

Comment: no i have used flush in other functions but here it is some wrong i think is the ob_flush and flush in their places ?

Comment: I do not see an ob_start in your script